# Why would priests, priestesses, shamans, monks, and nuns have the right to marry and to reproduce?

Tags: magic, society, religion, family

In my world, there are magical humans often called wizards (their scientific name is Homo magicus) (so, they are still humans, just not Homo sapiens).

They are traditionally a very religious race. Their society is a polytheistic theocracy, and is divided in five castes (from the purest to the most unclean):

1. Clergy (that includes monks and nuns, shamans, and priests and priestesses);
2. Rulers and warriors (that includes nobles, police officers, security guards, soldiers, and counter-terrorists);
3. Businesspeople and scientists (that includes farmers, traders, merchants, and medical doctors);
4. Artists, sportspeople, and workers (that includes professional singers, professional martial artists, electricians, plumbers, miners, and sex workers);
5. Untouchables/outcastes/outlaws (the homologues to Indian Dalits) (that includes street sweepers, latrine cleaners, pirates, criminal bikers, gangsters, mobsters, hitpeople, and spies).

In their religion, priests, priestesses, shamans, monks, and nuns can all marry and reproduce, but, in the case of monks and nuns, only some of them do legally, because if they want to marry and have children (either biologically or by adoption), they must do something useful for the Wizarding Empire.

Also, being a priest/priestess/shaman is hereditary: if possible, it is mandatory for priests, priestesses, and shamans to have at least one of their child to be a religious figure themself when becoming an adult.

Therefore, in the Wizard Empire, becoming a religious official is not gender-specific: women, men, cisgender people, transgender people, non-binary people, genderfluid people, dyadic people, and intersexed people can all become priests, shamans, and monks.

So, I wonder why would priests, priestesses, and shamans have the right to marry and to have biological children (in other words, the opposite to Roman Catholic Christian priests who must be dyadic cisgender men, and cannot marry, and therefore reproduce) (only dyadic cisgender men are also allowed to be Orthodox Christian priests, but they can marry only once, if I remember correctly).

Comment: What makes monk a monk and nun a nun?

Comment: why *shouldn't* they be able to marry? Judaism, sects of Christianity other than Roman Catholicism, and Islam all allow religious officials to marry, by the way. I don't know much about other religions, but I imagine most have no clauses about marriage for religious officials.

Comment: Ummm, a hereditary position DEMANDS progeny.

Comment: Because their religion is not stupid. There have been celibate sects that, well, naturally died out because of a lack of children.

Comment: What does "dyadic" mean?

Comment: . . . and what is the difference between a priest, priestess, shaman, monk, and a nun? Is it important?

Comment: While the priests of the Roman Catholic church are supposed to be celibate, there are enough cases where they weren't. The sexually active priest was a common story line in old tales and even in news stories today. One pope tried to get his son to follow him in office. A religion that follows human nature is more likely to have its rules followed.

Comment: VTC because (a) as the worldbuilding you can simply decide that your religion allows it. A great many religions on Earth allow its practitioners/leaders to marry and reproduce, and you don't explain why you're having a problem simply making it so. (b) The [help/dont-ask] states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally valid [and] you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question." (\*continued\*)

Comment: ... In other words, why are you asking this question? What's stopping you from solving the problem? How will you decide whether "God revealed it in scripture" or "In Friar Jacobsen's Monolith of 829 we learn..." or "Nobody's ever wondered if it's wrong?" is the best answer? Oddly, rather than explaining the tenets, history, and cultrual context of your religion, you spent time telling us that all of humanity's modern beliefs about gender are equal in your religion. Isn't that entirely irrelevant to the question? Could you provide (a lot) of the other data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, first off:  Your religion will probably not have monks and nuns.  Very few do.  Mostly Christianity and Buddhism, and the additional ones tend to be similar in their teachings, being either monotheistic or treating the many gods as not important to the philosophy driving them.

As for the rest, having both priests and priestesses and allowing them to marry is utterly commonplace.  Even in the Catholic church, the unmarried priest is not a matter of doctrine, but a choice that could be changed.  In Ancient Rome, the Pontifex Maximus was required to be married, and to have children, though he and his wife could adopt them once he received the role; this was because he could not oversee some rites, so he needed a wife to do so, and other rites required children to perform them.

This will reflect another aspect:  while your priests and priestesses will honor all the gods suitably, they may be limited in their own practice.  In Ancient Greece, a priest would a priest of Apollo at Delphi, and even at another shrine of Apollo be identical to non-priests.  There were also constraints such as certain rites of Artemis to be carried out by pubescent girls and of Athena, by a post-menopausal woman who no longer cohabited with her husband.  This may even *require* variation among the priests.

Answer (score 5):

## Why Not?

I think the real question is why you feel it is inherent to a religious life that a person not marry and be celibate?

- Through a big chunk of the middle ages, Catholic priests could and did marry. It wasn't until 1139 it became the rule. A priest was a part of the community. Most non-Catholic denominations allow priests to marry, and I think the married ones have a better perspective on real-life problems. Let's look at your specific world.
- Magic talent is linked to genetics, so it is likely the top caste is the most magical. OF COURSE you want to maximize your reproduction of the most genetically magical! But you could, if desired, be fairly evil about it if you like. The [lebensborn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebensborn) was a Nazi program to maximize the genetically 'correct' population by encouraging the purest Aryans to have children. But this often meant children were placed with good Aryan families to be raised, and an Aryan woman could (and by their standards should) be cranking out babies as fast as they could conceive and birth. Only in a religious context, sex and reproduction outside of marriage was considered immoral. Ergo, allow them to marry to have legitimate, genetically pure upper caste children.
- Obviously you can't have inherited jobs without inheritors. This means children. If assets pass to the church, there is always a risk that the wealth will move out of the hands of the upper caste and move through good works to the poor. This disrupts the whole framework of society, don't you know! Next thing, people will be expecting upward mobility.
- Marriage has always been more about codifying the transfer of wealth and legitimacy of offspring than any notions of romance or nuclear family. There is nothing to stop your priests from marrying, seeing their biologically compatible spouse for short reproductive interludes (possibly on the appropriately blessed religious holidays) and carrying on the rest of their lives (including romantic and sexual) without any involvement from an inconvenient and disruptive spouse.

Answer (score 5):

Because in their religion physical intimacy is not frowned upon and seen as a fact of life that doesn't contaminate or make people unclean.

It can even be that the religion prizes those who reproduce, giving new believers to the gods, so the members of the clergy have to walk the talk and reproduce, and I don't believe "doing something useful for the Empire" is something that generally annoys a member of the uppermost class.

Comment: You should totally reference Kushiel's Dart, in which religion and sex are intimately (!) entwined.

Answer (score 5):

[Clerical celibacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_celibacy) is something that is actually very specific to Catholicism. Most other Christian denominations allow clergy to marry. Some non-Christian religions (like Judaism or Islam) even *encourage* clergy to marry.

Nuns and monks are often an exception, but mostly because they are expected to focus completely on their spiritual development and not get distracted by any worldly emotions, like romance and sexuality. So it is not implausible that a monk or nun who is considered to have reached a certain level of spiritual development (proven by the deeds they have done) might be judged to be able to handle the distraction of a relationship with a spouse and may be granted the privilege to marry.

Comment: Some Protestant denominations require ministers to marry, following 1 Timothy 3.

Answer (score 3):

**To Make Babies**

[image]

They are allowed to get married so they can make babies and have a family. Many humans like this sort of thing.

To address your concerns, yes marriage is prohibited in the Catholic Church. But this is historically for practical and not religious reasons. It is not a religious commandment to be celibate. In principle the Pope could change the rules.

For the same reason, marriage is allowed in the Protestant and Orthodox Christian Churches.

Comment: Just for the record, there is no "Protestant Church". There are Protestant *churches*, and can range from the near-Catholic High Anglican congregations to the assorted congregations where believing Jesus was divine is optional.

Comment: @KeithMorrison I think you might have posted on the wrong answer.

Comment: I replied directly to the statement "For the same reason, marriage is allowed in the Protestant and Orthodox Christian Churches."

Comment: @KeithMorrison Hmm. . . then I am afraid I don't see what you are disagreeing with. I wrote "Churches". With an ess. Like the band.